# Does the Outlander have a Poor or Comfortable lifestyle?

Tags: dnd-5e, background, organized-play, dnd-adventurers-league

P. 3 of the Adventurer's League Player's Guide has a table indicating that an Outlander has a Poor lifestyle. However, Outlanders are proficient in Survival, and PHB. 159 says the following:

> Maintaining [a self-sufficient] lifestyle doesn’t require you to spend any coin, but it is time-consuming. *If you spend your time between adventures practicing a profession, as described in chapter 8, you can eke out the equivalent of a poor lifestyle*. **Proficiency in the Survival skill lets you live at the equivalent of a comfortable lifestyle**.

What's the verdict?

Comment: Hi Khashir; I've removed your last couple of questions as we don't do arbitrary story brainstorming/suggestions here. Our system doesn't handle it well.

Comment: Hi doppelgreener, is there a place here to discuss such matters? Thanks :) (and sorry, I can see why it can be a mess, given the answer/comment/chat model).

Comment: @Khashir we have a chat room! several in fact: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat is the main one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Poor***

*This *only* applies to their starting lifestyle for adventurer league play. For a home game you can let them *start* with whatever they want. It's important to remember that adventurer's league is a *specific* interpretation of the rules for organized play.

More importantly though, this gets at how downtime works in Adv League. Downtime days in Adv League work as a specific form of currency. When you complete a part of an adventure you get 10 days. To spend those days you pay a specific amount (the living expenses for your desired lifestyle level). ([ALPG](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/ADVLeague_PlayerGuide_TODv1_print.pdf) 5,6)

"Practicing a Profession" is a specific way to spend your downtime. Using it this way doesn't cost you anything, and normally a character in town can do this at a comfortable lifestyle (if trained in performance and you choose to use it, you can do so at wealthy). However, there is another option for this particular item. (PHB 187)

When you spend time "practicing a profession" and want to do so in the wilderness, you can do it and be considered poor. If you are trained in survival you can do it and be considered comfortable. However, neither of these things have anything to do with the starting lifestyle of someone trained in survival. (PHB 159)

It's also important to note that those are the default starting lifestyle expenses. You are free to go up or down if you want. If you wan to go down a level, simply spend a day paying at the lower level. If you want to go up a level, spend 30 days paying at the higher level. For *whatever* reason, they have decided that the Outlander should start at poor, this is obviously *not* respective of the fact that the background comes with training in survival, but merely a decision made by WOTC's organized play team.